# Clear calculator after refreshing or revisiting page

Tags: php, forms, calculator

I have a simple PHP form where i am calculating based on form field inputs. The form runs on the same page and calculates the figure to then display.
However at the moment, once i submit and it displays the value, this is then stored and displayed when i refresh or come back to the page again.
How can this be cleared so that the script is ran from fresh each time? (below is what i have):

```
<?php

    $finalSavings == 0;
    $value1 = $_POST['field1'];
    $value2 = $_POST['field2'];
    $value3 = $_POST['field3'];
    $value4 = $_POST['field4'];

    // Savings Calculations
    $final1 = ($value1 * 10) / 100;
    $final2 = ($value2 * 10) / 100;
    $final3 = ($value3 * 10) / 100;
    $final4 = ($value4 * 10) / 100;

    // Final Savings Calculations
    $finalSavings = $final1 + $final2 + $final3 + $final4;

    if ($finalSavings > 0 ) {
    echo $finalSavings;
    }

    ?>

<form id="savingsCalculator" method="post" action="<?php echo  esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" >
        <input type="number" name="field1" id="field1">
        <input type="number" name="field2" id="field2">
        <input type="number" name="field3" id="field3">
        <input type="number" name="field4" id="field4">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: if you open the link again it should not show your last inputs. Your provided code does not have any functionality in it that could achieve the effect you wrote

Comment: have you used any js code on this page ?